# In a Highchart, how to display the legend text in next row if the text is too long?

Tags: highcharts

I have highchart like **[this](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-legend)**.
How can I display the legend (*Firefox,IE,chrome...*) text in next row if the text is too long?
 Image describing my problem is [image: Here]

*P.S. I am not familiar with jQuery.*
Expecting a solution

Comment: [http://whathaveyoutried.com/](What have you tried)? This is not a give-me-the-code site. Show what you have tried yourself and where you got stuck.

Comment: In legend i tried like this, width, itemWidth,labelFormatter.. but no use i cant find the solution

Comment: **how can i fix this issue**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to make use of a `labelFormatter`

```
                labelFormatter: function() 
                {
                      var legendName = this.name;
                      var match = legendName.match(/.{1,10}/g);
                      return match.toString().replace(/\,/g,"<br/>");
                }
```

I have made an edit to the fiddle and you can find it **[Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/QQk8Z/3/)** It pushes the legend item text to next line after every 10 characters. Guess this is what you needed.
Hope this helps.

Comment: actually its not exactly i need. if the end, the next string will be placed on next line. for ex here in your text after is the last string in 1st row after that every comes to 2nd exactly i need this.

Comment: Can you please elaborate, may be with the aid of an example ?

Comment: result : product,price, place, and promation... here **product** displys 1st row and then **price, place,and promation** displays 2nd row. but here there is more sapce available in 1st row. this is my problem.

Comment: Do you have an image or a link of an example of how exactly your chart's legend should look like ?

Comment: You can upload image by editing your question. In the editor, you can find the image icon in the toolbar. click on the icon to upload the image.

Comment: i can't upload the images it needs more then 10 reputation to add a images. sorry man

Comment: can u give ur personal mail id i will sent u the issue image

Comment: In this case, have a check with your series name. There might actually be some white spaces in your series name as indicated in the legend.